# Make a service run indefinitely and communicate with activity

Tags: android, service, android-8.0-oreo

I Can't understand the differences on android services

I want to have a service run all the time in the background (activity recognition)

When it detect that I `RUN -> open GPS -> save curent longitude latitude -> if I stopped to run (WALKING) -> display the log lat on my MainActivity`

i want the service run if the user close the app , if the device is closed and re-open , if my service is killed

so I read about:

`[Started Service , Intent Service , Bound Service , Intent Bound Service , Job Scheduler , Job Intent Service]`.......But still i missing something

I understand that with Service `start_sticky` for `API<26` will run forever (if not killed) and with `IBinder` I can update the UI of my MainActivity; right?

My Many Q are ...:

**1.** Bound services can run for ever? and update my UI of MainActivity? do i need bound or i can achieve this with service or intent service

**2.** For oreo I "must" use `Job Scheduler` `->` `when killed` `->` `open again with broadcast receiver` `||` `work manager` `||` `alarm manager` `||`?

My questions are more for theory Answers not code.

NEED to `->` service for "ever" run `->` if (something) `->` open gps `->` save long lat `->` show long lat in UI of MainActivity.

Comment: there is yet another one term: `started foreground service` (see `Service#startForeground()` method) - this is what you probably need

Comment: sorry i did mention that , i have read it but the drawback is the constant notification to the user...and u know user don't like it very much... thank u for your answer

Comment: You can't rely on communicating with activity directly since started services can outlive activities. You need to persist the update data (in database for example) and notify activity with bind/broadcast in case it's still alive, and otherwise fetch the data when activity is restarting.

Comment: @LightsOn users don't like their phones losing ton of battery life for unknown reason either, thats mostly why notifications are enforced in order to maintain services alive. You might've not noticed, but since android Oreo there's a lot of limitations regarding `BroadcastReceiver`s for that reason as well.

Comment: notification is something made by google guys on **purpose** so that the user knows whats happening on his device

Comment: Also - if you've tried to start a background service through (one of whitelisted) `BroadcastReceiver`s or a `JobScheduler` on android O, You'll experience a runtime exception because it's no longer allowed (foreground services are allowed though).

Comment: @Pawel are you sure you cannot even start it? i though you can start them but the service has to finish within very short time

Comment: @pskink running scheduled job/receiving an intent is possible, i mean explicitly calling `startService` from within those.

Comment: yes i understand this .. but i can't understand the Service itself ... i know that i need to store the data and fetch them in time , but the Service it's a new concept for me and i can't understand how to make a service to run "for ever" in the background..thank u for your answer

Comment: @Pawel ok got it - indeed: *"The startService() method now throws an IllegalStateException if an app targeting Android 8.0 tries to use that method in a situation when it isn't permitted to create background services."*

Comment: I'd like to say it's possible but it's not - before Oreo people used to hook into multiple broadcasts to restart their service as often as possible to keep it alive, some custom ROMs (like Xiaomi) already used to block those, but android team decided they'll put in additional restrictions. You might also encounter **doze** mode which delays `JobScheduler` once user kept his phone idle for some time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To keep a `Service` running indefinitely in the background, use a [foreground service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services). This will force you to maintain a visible notification/nav bar icon; that's the price Android extracts from you in exchange for keeping your service running for a long time period. Supported on API 5+.

`JobScheduler/WorkManager/AlarmManager` won't *prevent* your `Service` from being killed. They can be used to bring your `Service` back to life. Also, `JobScheduler` and `WorkManager` can get your system out of [doze](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby), so you can do useful work. A [`WakeLock`](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock) may also be necessary. If the user *explicitly terminates* your app, `JobScheduler` jobs will no longer wake it up. I don't know of any good, "Android-approved" way to resuscitate an app in this circumstance. Although, even on Oreo+, you can register to receive [these intents](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions), which you can use to regain execution.

You can make any of the `Service` subclasses you mentioned into a foreground service (by calling `startForeground()`. The choice of subclass is a matter of convenience, and depends on how you would like to dispatch & schedule your work. Your app could just as easily be implemented with the base-class `Service`.

`START_STICKY` doesn't actually prevent a `Service` from stopping. It's more like a request to the system: "After you kill my app/service, please restart it, if/when you see fit". In my opinion, it is not an effective way of keeping a `Service` running for a long period of time. If a `Service` is not in the foreground, and no other application components are in the foreground (e.g., on screen), then Android can kill your app quite quickly. This is more true of later versions of the OS (Oreo+).

Your `Service` will need to be bound to other components (e.g., `Activities`) from time to time. You bind to a `Service` so you can 1.) Make sure it exists and 2.) Carry out communications with it (call functions on it, etc.). So, yes, with `IBinder`, you can update the UI of your MainActivity.

Binding a `Service` doesn't make it run forever. If your `Activity` is bound to the `Service`, you can be confident that the `Service` will stick around for as long as the `Activity` is onscreen. Once it leaves the screen, all bets are off.

In other words, Android is very likely to kill an app/service when it's not in the foreground, and not bound to any components that are in the foreground (onscreen).

A `Service` can generally open up an `Activity` at any time it chooses, simply by calling `startActivity()`. Your `Activity` can even dismiss the keyguard (in certain circumstances), using `FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD`.

If you can tolerate less frequent location updates, you may be able to do this without staying in the foreground, [but there are limitations](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits).

Comment: What a beautiful answer!! THANK YOU VERY MUCH ... i think that its a good starting point for me to understand the android services...